# How to prevent onTap on area outside flutter ClipRRect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using ClipRRect to clip the drawer to obtain the following shape.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt7Sn.png)

Here is Drawer container

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(250)),
  child: Drawer(
    child: ListView( 
      children: <Widget>[
        MainDrawerHeader(),
        MainDrawerListTile('Home', Icons.home, HomeScreen.routeName),
        MainDrawerListTile('SMS Templates', Icons.text_fields, SmsTemplatesScreen.routeName),
        MainDrawerListTile('Profile', Icons.person, ProfileScreen.routeName),
        MainDrawerListTile('Settings', Icons.settings, SettingsScreen.routeName),
        MainDrawerListTile('Contact Us', Icons.contact_phone, ContactUsScreen.routeName),
        MainDrawerListTile('Help', Icons.help, HelpScreen.routeName),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

And here is ListTile (clickable drawer item)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.red,  
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text(
      tileTitle,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
    onTap: () => onListTileTap(context),
    leading: Icon(
      tileIcon,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 14, 212, 1),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: `drawer: Container(
  width: 200,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(100))),
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 32,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => FlatButton(onPressed: () => print('$i pressed'), child: Text('item $i', textScaleFactor: 2,)),
  )
),`

Comment: Ok.. it's working with container. But what is the solution using ClipRRect or there is none?

Comment: why would you want `ClipRRect` if `ShapeDecoration` is working?

Comment: Never mind! Just asking out of curiosity. If i need it to use in scenario where use of ClipRRect is must.